# How does this specific piece of external copy/paste code get called if the script it relies on loads asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, external-script

I've noticed a lot of third party monitoring tools that you need to copy and paste into your website follows this pattern:

```
<!-- For example, Loggly -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cloudfront.loggly.com/js/loggly.tracker-latest.min.js" async></script>
  <script>
      var _LTracker = _LTracker || [];
      _LTracker.push({'logglyKey': 'blah-blah-blah',
      'sendConsoleErrors' : true,
      'tag' : 'loggly-jslogger'  });
  </script>
```

For efficiency's sake, the `loggly.tracker-latest.min.js` is being loaded `async`, which is great.

My understanding of this line: `var _LTracker = _LTracker || [];` is that it's saying in case when it's called `_LTracker` hasn't loaded yet from the `loggly.tracker-latest.min.js`, then initialize a blank array `[]` to push the data.

In the situation above where the data containing `logglyKey` is in a newly init Array, then the only way to actually capture that info is if the external script `loggly.tracker-latest.min.js`, once it finishes loading, has some code (not visible here) that then redefines `_LTracker` and pulls in any information previously initialized in an empty Array. Right? Like, there's no way the code as it is visibly written moves the `logglyKey` info from the blank Array to the actual `_LTracker`...

Because so, I reasoned that I could also choose to modify the code myself below

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cloudfront.loggly.com/js/loggly.tracker-latest.min.js" async></script>
  <script>
      $(window).on("load",function() {
        var _LTracker = _LTracker;
        _LTracker.push({'logglyKey': 'blah-blah-blah',
        'sendConsoleErrors' : true,
        'tag' : 'loggly-jslogger'  });
      })
  </script>
```

However the code above actually fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`, because `_LTracker` wasn't yet defined. But I'm not sure why because `window.on("load")` should have waited for the external script to load?

Comment: The `load` event doesn't wait for `async` scripts. Use `defer` instead of `async` and it will be executed before `load`.

Comment: @Barmar `defer` didn't work either